# In a Universal App how can you convert or reuse a modal view as a popover?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uipopovercontroller, ios-universal-app

I have a modal view controller that is displayed using:

```
[self presentModalViewController:addStoryItem animated:YES];
```

on the iPhone. I'm converting the app to a Universal App and I want to display the same modal using a popover. There's a really good tutorial on popovers [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial), but it focuses on creating the popover for iPad from scratch.

Should I create an ~ipad version of the AddStoryItem.xib file and display it as a popover, or can I display the existing sans-~ipad file? Or, should I just create a specific popover for iPad even though the content of the popover is exactly how I want it on the iPad version?

Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You COULD do either. You could simply use the same one (assuming it has the correct auto-sizing masks, it might not look half bad) but I think Apple would suggest that you create a new one that uses the greater space available on the ipad better and display that one.

Also of note, Apple strongly discourages full-screen transitions so which ever method you choose, be sure to change the modal presentation style to be one of the ipad-specific modal popovers. Check out this site: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/5/3/ipad-modal-view-controllers.html and the **"Modal Presentation Styles"** section

Answer (score 0):

thats depends on what you want to display on the UIPopOver .. you can use the same iphone xib in case you assign the content size for the popOver similar to iphone view size (320,460).